# Macos 10.12.2 apache ssl

Tags: macos, apache, ssl

I have update my MacOS to 10.12.2 and after that the ssl on my apache is not working. I tried to create new keys and also reset my `httpd-ssl.conf` file but no luck. When I am enabling the ssl for my apache the apache is not responding at all. Not even the http pages on `http://localhost`.
In my console I have these errors

```
[Wed Dec 14 22:30:06.977332 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 11836] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)

(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

[Wed Dec 14 22:30:07.016531 2016] [mpm_prefork:alert] [pid 11836] no listening sockets available, shutting down

[Wed Dec 14 22:30:07.016540 2016] [:emerg] [pid 11836] AH00019: Unable to open logs, exiting
```

Although if I disable the ssl the apache works fine. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the certification on keychain had the issue. So i just create new certifications and update them accordingly and now it's fine.

Here it is a walkthrough if you want to setup your local ssl
https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/774e4b0b3d4d739cbc53